# How to find out if the application has been restarted?

Tags: java, eclipse, restart, exit-code

We're building an application in Java based on Eclipse. Its entry point implements `IApplication`. In some cases, we let Eclipse restart the application by returning the exit code `IApplication.EXIT_RESTART`.

How can we differentiate between the appliation being started initially and being restarted?

```
org.eclipse.equinox.launcher 1.3.100v20150511-1540
```

Comment: Maybe you could use this work around: Set a flag in a file if the application is exited using `IApplication.EXIT_RESTART` and check for that flag on every startup.

Comment: I don't think there is any standard indicator so you will have to arrange something yourself.